# Getting error while adding SVG content in type script

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-redux

I am migrating java script file to type script and getting error like ***Cannot find name 'svg'.ts(2304)***

Below is the Java script file i am trying to migrate

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from 'example.css';

export default () => (
    <svg viewBox="0,0,48,44" focusable="false">
        <path className={styles.Fill} d="M0,0h480z" />
        <path
            className={styles.Grey}
            d="M31.9,1.5,4.5-4.5
        s.3z"
        />
    </svg>
);
```

Looking for help in fixing this.
Below is the type script file.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here.

1. Modifying the file to file.tsx will resolve "Cannot find name 'svg'.ts(2304)". [TypeScript docs on JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)
2. Using css module in ts requires some extra configuration. [How to use CSS Modules with TypeScript and webpack](https://medium.com/@sapegin/css-modules-with-typescript-and-webpack-6b221ebe5f10)

Need to modify tsconfig.json

```
{
     "compilerOptions": {
         ...
         "jsx": "react",
         ...
     }
}
```

Comment: 1: Still issue is there after renaming to .tsx
2: CSS issue fixed

Comment: @Ganesh Still "Cannot find name 'svg'.ts (2304)" is this wrong?

Comment: @Ganesh Your file name is still file.ts is not file.tsx, what is the error message after changing to file.tsx?

Comment: added 2 screenshots, one with .ts and other with .tsx

Comment: @Ganesh Need to modify tsconfig.json, the answer has been updated.

Comment: "jsx": "react" is already available in config file. still getting error

Comment: {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": false,
        "inlineSourceMap": false,
        "inlineSources": false,
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "instrumentation": ["src/utils/instrumentation/index"]
        },
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200694/discussion-between-snow-and-ganesh).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `import * as React from 'react'`?
you may not have synthetic imports enabled.

Also if your css is at the same level in the folder hierarchy as your component you will need to `import styles from '.\example.css`

Comment: Tried bu no luck with import * as React from 'react'